# Can a 3D curve not confined to a plane have fractal dimension anywhere between $1$ and $3$?

Tags: curves, fractals

I have a question regarding my dissertation I could not find an answer to:

> Can a 3D-Curve (whose graph goes in all three directions of space) have a Fractal Dimension (FD) anywhere between $1$ and $3$, depending on its space filling capability?

The context of my question is as follows: a [space filling curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) in 2D-Space has a FD of $2$. A space filling curve in 3D-Space has a FD of $3$, e.g a [3D Hilbert Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension).

A non-space filling curve that lies in 2D-Space (e.g a 2D Koch Curve) should have a FD between $1$ and $2$, depending on its complexity/ space filling capability. And such a curve that in 3D-Space should have a FD between $1$ and $3$?

N.B at first I thought that a curve in 3D-Space should have a FD between 2 and 3, e.g the [3D-Sierpinski Arrowhead Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_curve), which should have the same FD of $2.32$ as the [3D Sierpinski Gasket](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/polyhedral). However I came to the conclusion that a 3D-Curve could be simple enough to have a FD below $2$ (also backed by box-counting measurments I made). A 3D Curve which my 3D Box-Counting Algorithm says has a FD of $1.52$.

[image]

Regards

Comment: A smooth curve in 3D certainly has fractal dimension 1. Instead, you need special constructions to point out curves having a higher fractal dimension.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, a smooth curve in 3D that is straigth should have a FD of 1? And if it is wavy in its path it should have a FD between 1 and 3?

Comment: I meant "smooth" (differentiable), "straight" would mean a straight line, clearly one-dimensional. For a dimension $>1$, you don't need just "wavy", but "fractal".

Comment: Oh sorry, I see. I also meant a 3D curve which is fractal.

Comment: Thank you for the edit Blue : )

Comment: One example of a smooth 1D curve embedded in 3D space but not confined to a 2D plane: a helix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix